# How to reset or discard the buffered data

Tags: go, buffer, reader

Not able to reset or discard the buffer.

I am trying to get the data over the serial port where I am getting data packet of some fixed length for every 10 seconds. I have an infinite for loop to receive the data packets continuously. After receiving the new data packet I am resetting the buffer but when I receive the next data packet, it overwrites the buffer and I get mixed data packet.

Let say I should receive packet `abcdef` continuously for every n second. But when I try the following code I am receiving packet `bcdefa` then after n second `cdefab` then `defabc` and so on

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "time"
    "github.com/tarm/serial"
)

func main() {
    c := &serial.Config{Name: "/dev/ttyUSB0", Baud: 57600}
    s, err := serial.OpenPort(c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second / 2)
        reader := bufio.NewReader(s)
        pck, err := reader.Peek(46)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        go parse(pck)
        reader.Reset(s)
    }
}
```

How do I reset or discard the buffer data effectively so that I will receive the exact data packet.

Comment: The buffer is discarded every loop iteration. Can you explain what you mean by "in the next packet it overwrites somewhere"?

Comment: The `reader.Reset` is pointless - in the line immediately following, the entire reader is discarded.

Comment: bufio.NewReader returns its argument if possible. Given your problem description, serial.OpenPort returns a buffered reader already, and since you never advance it it makes sense that you get the same bytes over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

bare in mind i cant check what i m saying here...

1/ you must not instantiate the bufio reader at each iteration

2/ bufio.Reader.Peek does NOT advance the reader
https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Peek

3/ Unless you get a malformed packet, i think you dont need to reset at all.

4/ Please indent your code at play.golang.org

5/ You are not checking the read error for termination

6/ All package i can found to work with serial ports in go exposes an instance of io.Reader, so it might be useless to use an additional bufio.Reader. I suspect you r using https://godoc.org/github.com/tarm/serial#OpenPort

This is probably not the definitive answer, but it should help.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    s, err := serial.OpenPort(c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    pck := make([]byte, 46)
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second / 2)
        n, err := s.Read(pck)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            log.Println(err)
        }
        pck = pck[:n]
        go parse(pck)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have indented the code in the question. I have tried your method but it is not receiving the whole packet.

Comment: @Logan make a new question with both server and client that you wrote so far.